# Calculate row datas and select them

Tags: mysql, join, distance, self-join

Below is what I have in the table 'myTable':

| COMPANY | pointX | pointY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MICROSOFT | 12.434 | 76.810 |
| AMAZON | 1.779 | 290.122 |
| APPLE | 601.840 | 333.910 |

What I have to do is set MICROSOFT as the datum point,

and calculate the distance between each company and sum them in a new column.

I tried to make a query, but I guess it's a bit complex for me.

Comment: Why did you edit this question? and changed the example?  You already accepted an answer, so it's very unclear why you did this change.

Comment: Just some random "First Name"s cannot be sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join:

```
SELECT t1.COMPANY,
       ABS(t2.pointX - t1.pointX) + ABS(t2.pointY - t1.pointY) DISTANCE
FROM myTable t1 INNER JOIN myTable t2
ON t2.COMPANY <> t1.COMPANY
WHERE t2.COMPANY = 'Carlos';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32a69a29f08c2138ffd89b9fcb949cdb).